# Cycle index of a symmetric group defined by recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

It is claimed in a text I am reading that the cycle index of the symmetric group satisfies the recurrence relation $$Z(S_n)=n^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^n{s_kZ(S_{n-k})}$$

This is presented without explanation, much less proof. The standard presentation in terms of the partitions of n is presented earlier and makes sense to me, but this isn't as clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard presentation is indeed in terms of partitions e.g. in the Lovasz text *Combinatorial problems and exercises.* A good device to help remember the recurrence is the fact that the OGF of the cycle index of the symmetric group is given by $$G(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} Z(S_q) z^q =
\exp\left(a_1 z + a_2 \frac{z^2}{2} + a_3 \frac{z^3}{3} + \cdots\right).$$

Differentiate to obtain
$$G'(z) = G(z) \left(a_1 + a_2 z + a_3 z^2 + a_4 z^3 + \cdots\right).$$

Extracting coefficients from this with the Cauchy product we get
$$[z^n] G'(z) = (n+1) Z(S_{n+1}) = \sum_{k=0}^n Z(S_k) a_{n+1-k}$$

which is
$$Z(S_{n}) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k Z(S_{n-k}).$$

**Remark.** The OGF is derived from the labeled EGF for the combinatorial class

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{A}_1 \times \textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{A}_2 \times \textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \mathcal{A}_3 \times \textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z}) + \cdots).$$